# How to get a specific repeated route from table

Tags: sql

How to get a repeated route from the give table?

**Input:**

| src | Dest |
| --- | --- |
| Pune | Delhi |
| Pune | Mumbai |
| Mumbai | Pune |
| Delhi | Jaipur |
| Jaipur | Jodhpur |

**Output:**

| src | Dest |
| --- | --- |
| Pune | Mumbai |

Comment: Please do not spam the tag. What database are you using ?

Comment: Why is Pune to Mumbai considered "repeated"? I don't see it duplicated in the sample table

Comment: It is like show the same route for travelling it doesn't matter A to B or B to A

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As Squirrel said in the comments, please restrict yourself to one database.

This however should work in most:

```
SELECT t1.*
FROM YourTable t1
INNER JOIN YourTable t2
ON t1.src = t2.dest AND t1.dest = t2.src
WHERE t1.src > t1.dest;
```

By way of explanation, the where clause is there to ensure that you only return single records, otherwise it would return both Pune, Mumbai and Mumbai, Pune.